# How to show incremental changes in SQL

Tags: sql, database, presto

I have a sql (Presto) table that contains data about different kinds of bird species. The table contains information about how often the different species have been observed in a park over different months. Some of the species have not been observed in certain months, but measurements were only performed on `07-9-19`, `08-10-19`, and `05-11-19`. A sample of the data would look like this

```
Species        Period     Total (Cumulative) Observations (TCO)

Bird1           07-9-19            33
Bird1           08-10-19           45
Bird1           05-11-19           60
Bird2           07-9-10            20
Bird3            ....            ....
Bird3            ....            ....
....             ....            ....
```

What I would like is to add a new column to this table that captures incremental change between two days of measurement for each species. Based on the example sample I would like to produce the following result:

```
Species        Period            TCO        Change

Bird1           07-9-19            33          33
Bird1           08-10-19           45          12
Bird1           05-11-19           60          15
Bird2           07-9-10            20          20
Bird3           08-10-19           5           5
Bird3           05-11-19           24          19
....             ....            ....
```

I think I've found [a way to do this](https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/how-to-use-values-from-previous-or-next-rows-in-a-query-in-sql-server/), but it is quite complicated and involves creating a new table. I was wondering if there was are simpler solution to my problem (as it is slightly simpler than the problem in the link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [window function `lag()`](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/window.html) to recover the previous tco for the same species, period-wise:

```
select 
    t.*,
    tco - lag(tco, 1, 0) over(partition by species order by period) change
from mytable
```

The three-argument form of lag lets you specify a default value instead of `null`: as per your expected result, you want `0` in that case.