# show difference between of two price list

Tags: php, mysql, date, select, window-functions

I have history list of product price(order by created_at) like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [product_id] => 49
            [price] => 14520000.0000
            [created_at] => 1592501154
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [product_id] => 49
            [price] => 14000000.0000
            [created_at] => 1592587554
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [product_id] => 49
            [price] => 14800000.0000
            [created_at] => 1592673954
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [product_id] => 49
            [price] => 10000000.0000
            [created_at] => 1592760354
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [product_id] => 49
            [price] => 14000000.0000
            [created_at] => 1592846754
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 7
            [product_id] => 49
            [price] => 14000000.0000
            [created_at] => 1592933154
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 8
            [product_id] => 49
            [price] => 14000000.0000
            [created_at] => 1593019554
        )

)
```

Now for show data in table I listed price using `foreach` method like this:

```
   <?php foreach($product_prices_list as $product_price_list):?>
     <tr>
         <td><?= esc($product_price_list->created_at);?></td>
         <td class="text-center"><?= esc(number_format($product_price_list->price));?></td>
         <td class="text-center"></td> //show difference between of two price
     </tr>
   <?php endforeach;?>
```

I can see true output in table but I need to show difference between of two price  in the third column like this picture:

[image]

how do can i show difference between of two price in my list?!

Comment: What is the compared price? 14,000,000?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A10676716+lag+over+partition+by&mixed=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to compare the current price property to the price from the previous object in the array?

Something like this should work:

```
<?php foreach($product_prices_list as $key => $product_price_list):?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= esc($product_price_list->created_at);?></td>
        <td class="text-center"><?= esc(number_format($product_price_list->price));?></td>
        <td class="text-center"><?= (!empty($product_prices_list[$key - 1])) ? $product_prices_list[$key + 1]->price - $product_price_list->price: 0; ?></td> //show difference between of two price
    </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: I think u should change `$key - 1` to `$key + 1`.

Comment: @H3llC0d3r I just modified the answer. It looked like the records are from oldest to newest, so `$key - 1` was to compare to the previous record.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can compute this information directly in the database using window functions:

```
select
    t.*,
    price 
        - lag(price, 1, price) over(partition by product_id order by created_at) 
        as price_diff
from mytable t
```

This adds one more column to your resultset, that contains the difference between the current price and the previous price of the same product.

Comment: Might you close this duplicate question that you've answered in the same way (several times) in the past? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58493777/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/62160774/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/58884303/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/59545334/2943403 ,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216390/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/62076357/2943403 The "close" link is between "follow" and "flag" under the question.